# Insert Date(ISODate) field into MongoDB using java client

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to insert a document into Mongo via Java code. One of the fields in the document is a Date (java.util.Date). The expectation is to store it as ISODate(). However, within Mongo, it shows up as NumberLong("")

I have referred various similar questions, but none seem to actually solve the problem. Has anyone actually done this successfully.

The class is being serialised into a Document using Jackson ObjectMapperFactory. Here is the screenshot(expireTS is the field)

[image]

Actual object is :

[image]

Comment: If you send it as a date then it would show as ISODate(), otherwise if you send it as timestamp then it would usually be a string or can be NumberLong() depends on how it's inserted. Can you give us insertion code & Have date in first place or you might need to convert timestamp into date before insertion :: `import java.sql.Timestamp; import java.util.Date; public class TimestampToDateExample1 { public static void main(String args[]){ Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(yourTimeStamp); Date date=new Date(ts.getTime()); } } `

Comment: I have used Date(expiresAt) and not timestamp, as shown in the second screenshot. Not sure, why it gets converted to NumberLong